# Looking for mussar on not thinking oneself wise

Tags: mussar-ethics, mishlei

Shalom.

Mishlei makes clear that one should not think oneself wise and that it is very dangerous to do so.

From what I can see [(from Mishlei 26:16)](https://www.sefaria.org/Proverbs.26.16?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), diligence is one way - the only way? - of overcoming this bad middah.

Does anyone have any more counsel on avoiding this bad middah than what I have gleaned above?

Many thanks.

Comment: Do you have a verse that says explicitly that it is bad to think oneself wise? In many places in Mishlei it speaks about how wisdom is an important trait.

Comment: In sefer דרך אמונה it is explained that this posuk means that one should not speak in front of someone that is wiser than him.

Comment: @Dov - the verse I was thinking of was Mishlei 26:12.

Comment: This verse is more a reference to someone who thinks that they are wise but it is not really the case.

Comment: @Shmuel - thanks, that is helpful. :)

Comment: @Dov - ya, that’s the bad middah I am looking for mussar regarding (thinking oneself wise when one is not).

Comment: For a minute I thought you were referring to [Jeremiah 9:22-23](https://www.sefaria.org/Jeremiah.9.22-23?lang=bi)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Chovos Halevavos](https://www.sefaria.org/Duties_of_the_Heart%2C_Eighth_Treatise_on_Examining_the_Soul.3.206?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) gives a good barometer.

> He said: "Do not be overly wise", since wisdom has a fixed limit which cannot be crossed. The explanation is that all the various branches of wisdom which lead to the service of G-d, guarding His commandments, or demonstrating His wisdom and power - this category is permitted to us, and it is our duty to investigate it, as written: "Behold, the fear of the L-ord is wisdom" ([Iyov 28:28](https://www.sefaria.org/Job.28.28?lang=bi)), and "The fear of the L-ord is the beginning of wisdom: and the knowledge of the holy ones (good deeds/traits) is understanding" ([Mishlei 9:10](https://www.sefaria.org/Proverbs.9.10?lang=bi)), which means knowledge of G-d, and also: "The fear of the L-ord is the beginning of wisdom" ([Tehilim 111:10](https://www.sefaria.org/Psalms.111.10?lang=bi)), and "The wise men are ashamed, they are dismayed and taken; lo, they have rejected the word of the L-ord; and what wisdom is in them?" ([Yirmiyahu 8:9](https://www.sefaria.org/Jeremiah.8.9?lang=bi)), and all that is a wisdom outside of this way we mentioned - it is forbidden to study it and investigate after it. Therefore he said: "do not be overly wise". (Sefaria translation and notation)

So we see, there are certain aspects of wisdom which should be pursued, but when they fall outside the realms of our G-d and His Torah, this "wisdom" is what should be ignored.

Ultimately, as with many things, maintaining a sense of humility is crucial. [Pirkei Avos 4:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Pirkei_Avot.4.1?lang=bi&with=Commentary%20ConnectionsList&lang2=en) famously notes:

> Ben Zoma said: Who is wise? He who learns from every man, as it is said: “From all who taught me have I gained understanding” ([Psalms 119:99](https://www.sefaria.org/Psalms.119.99?lang=bi)).